# preg_match title and ID

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all

Our script uses `preg_match` to determine if the url is correct and if it's not it throws a 404, except we want our urls to look like this:

```
http://www.my-domain.com/my-post-title-here/my_id_here/
```

When it originates as this:

```
http://www.my-domain.com/my-post-title-here-my_id_here.html
```

So we tried to change the preg_match to the following but its not working,

```
preg_match('(([a-z]+)/([0-9]+))/?', request_uri(), $matches);
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well we got the preg_match to work using the following,

```
preg_match('#([a-z])/(\d+)/$#i', request_uri(), $matches);
```

But we still cant get it to restrict to just the seo title, for example.

If the url looks like this

http://www.my-domain.com/my-post-title-here/my_id_here/

You can still load the post by replacing the post title with anything you want, which could result in duplicate content issues!

How can we restrict it to just the title of the post as that's how we generate the url??